# Find/Replace string that doesn't contain quotes

Tags: regex, vim

I have inherited a rather large/ugly php codebase (language is unimportant, this is a generic vim question) , where nothing is quoted properly (old php doesn't mind, but new php versions throw warnings).

I'd like to turn $something[somekey] into $something['somekey'], only if its not already quoted or contain the character $

I was trying to build a regular expression to quote the keys, but just cant seem to be able get it to cooperate.

This is what i have so far, which doesn't work but maybe will help explain my question better. And to show that i have actually tried.

```
:%s/\v\$(.{-})\[(['"$]@<!.{-})\]/$\1['\2']/
```

My goal is to have something like this:

```
$something[somekey]            = $something['somekey']
$somethingelse[someotherthing] = $something['someotherthing']
$another['key']                = $another['key'] (is ignored)
$yetanother["keykey"]          = $yetanother["keykey"] (is ignored)
$derp[$herp]                   = $derp[$herp] (is ignored)
$array[3]                      = $array[3] (is ignored)
```

These can appear anywhere in text, even multiple on the same line, and even touching each other like $something[key]$something[key2], which i would like to be replaced with $something['key']$something['key2']

Another problem, there seems to be random javascript arrays in some files.. which have [] square brackets. So the regex needs to check to see if it starts with $ and text before the brackets.

Im probably asking for the impossible, but any help on this would be great before i go insane editing each file one by one manually.

EDIT: forgot that keys can be numeric, and shouldn't be quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following, which processed everything from your question correctly:

```
:%s/\[\(\I\i*\)\]/['\1']/g
```

Or, with optional white spaces inside the parens:

```
:%s/\[\s*\(\I\i*\)\s*\]/['\1']/g
```

And also checking for `$identifier` before the parens:

```
:%s/\(\$\i\+\)\[\s*\(\I\i*\)\s*\]/\1['\2']/g
```

Comment: Ah, thats great! i just have one small problem, some extra criteria that i didn't think of. $something[1] is perfectly valid, so any chance there is a way of modifying this to ignore numbers?

Comment: Wow, perfect. Thank you so much, you've probably saved me so many hours and hair pulling :)

Comment: @Ollie I'm glad I could help. I don't know PHP syntax, but have a look at vim's help on character classes on `:help pattern`. I don't know if leading underscores would be treated correctly. BTW: I suppose you know how to execute the replacement command on multiple files?

Comment: i do, yes. But this project is such a mess i need to run it a file at a time, and fix any quote mismatches that can occur.

Comment: +1 Nice use of `\I` and `\i`. It may do some good to take advantage of `\zs` & `\ze` and very magic, `\v`, for some of these substitutions. e.g. `%s/\[\zs\I\i*\ze\]/'&'/g` and `%s/\v\$\i+\[\zs\s*(\I\i*)\s*\ze\]/'\1'/g`. These make the replacement part of the substitution a bit simpler. See `:h /\zs` and `:h /\v` for more information.

Comment: @PeterRincker Thanks, I learnt something today. Until now, I've never dared to take a look at those parts of the `:pattern` docu :)